Proving a matrix is diagonalizable
Consider the matrix $M\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -6 & -6 \\
-1 & 4 & 2\\
3 &-6&-4
\end{pmatrix}.$$ I need to show that $M$ is diagonalizable, and find a matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}MS$ is diagonal.
I have found that $P_M(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+5\lambda^2-8\lambda+4=(\lambda-2)(\lambda-1)(-\lambda+2).$
So, the eigenvalues are $\lambda=1$, $\lambda=2$, with algebraic multiplicity of 1 and 2, respectively.
Eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ has algebraic multiplicity 1. We know that the geometric multiplicity is $dim(ker(M-I))$, and given that $1$ is an eigenvalue, there exists at least one $v\in E_1$. Otherwise, $1$ wouldn't be an eigenvalue of $M$. Therefore, geometric multiplicity must be greater or equal than 1. We also know that geometric multiplicity $\leq$ algebraic multiplicity, since algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ is 1, it follows that 1$\geq$ geometric multiplicity $=$1. I.e $dim(E_1)=1$
So, we have to solve \begin{align*}
(M-I)v&=0 &&\\
\begin{pmatrix}
4&-6&-6\\
-1&3&2\\
3&-6&-5
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
I have obtained by using row operations:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&-1\\
0&1&1/3\\
0&0&0
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
So we have a system
\begin{align*}
x-z&=0 &\\
y+(1/3)z&=0
\end{align*}
Setting $x=1$ gives
$z=1$ and $y=-1/3$. So, let $v_1=(1,-1/3,1)$. It's possible to check that $v_1$ satisfies $(M-I)v=0$. We say that $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $M$ associated to $\lambda=1$.
Let's solve $(M-2I)v=0$. We have that $$\begin{pmatrix}
3&-6 &-6 \\
-1&2&2\\
3 &-6&-6
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Using row operations, we get that $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&-2 &-2 \\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\end{pmatrix}.$$
This is an equation $x-2y-2z=0$, i.e. $x=2(y+z)$.
Setting $x=1$ gives $z=1/2-y$.
But how can I proceed after this? How to find the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda=2$?

Find the null space associated with the matrix $M-2I$, and if this null-space is of dimension $2$, then $M$ is diagonalizable, since the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 2$ are linearly independent.

You should not take specific values for $x$, $y$ or $z$.
Let
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\\ z \end{bmatrix}$$
You showed that
$$X \in \operatorname{Ker}(A - 2I_3) \iff x-2y-2z=0$$
that is to say
$$X \in \operatorname{Ker}(A - 2I_3) \iff X = \begin{bmatrix}2y+2z\\ y\\ z \end{bmatrix} = y \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + z  \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore $\operatorname{Ker}(A - 2I_3)$ is spanned by the two following vectors
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\quad \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
which are clearly linearly independent. So one can conclude $\dim \operatorname{Ker}(A - 2I_3) = 2$.

Thanks! When I try to do an analogous process for $ker(M-I)$, I get that: Let $v=\begin{pmatrix} x\ y\ z\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $v\in ker(M-I)\iff v=\begin{pmatrix} x\  (-1/3)z\ x \end{pmatrix}= x\begin{pmatrix} 1\ 0\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}0\ -1/3\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Is this correct? Do these two vectors I found span $ker(M-1)$?

No. It does not work because you have $x=z$ here (you have to take into account all the equations on $x$, $y$ and $z$). So you get $v = \begin{bmatrix} x \ (-1/3)x \ x \end{bmatrix} = x \begin{bmatrix} 1 \ -1/3 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ so it is spanned by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \ -1/3 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Again, thanks! And these vectors $(1, -1/3, 1), (2, 1, 0), (2, 0, 1)$ will be the columns of matrix $S$, right?

Yes, exactly !!
